# Function to change a letter into a word

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

This is my text file that is an input to the program:

```
Id Title Copy 
B2002010 gyh 1 
D2001001 abc 12 
M2003005 zxc 3 
D2002003 qwe 13 
M2001002 efg 1 
D2001004 asd 6 
D2003005 zxc 3 
M2001006 wer 6 
D2001006 wer 6 
B2004008 sxc 10 
D2002007 sdf 9 
D2004008 sxc 10
```

ID is formatted as Xyyyyrrr where:

- X is B => Book or M => Magazine
- yyyy is the year
- rrr is a random number

What I have to do is that the first letter needs to be changed into a word.

For example:

```
(D2002,24) --> Dictionary,2002,24
```

My Spark project is on Eclipse and I am using Maven and Scala IDE l.

```scala
package bd.spark_app 
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext 
import org.apache.spark.sql._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType 
import scala.io.Source 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray 
import org.apache.log4j._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row 
import scala.Array 

object alla { def main(args:Array[String]) = { 

    val conf  =newSparkConf().setMaster("local")
    .setAppName("trying   ") 
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
    val x = 
    sc.textFile("/home/hadoopusr/sampledata") 

    val converted = x.map(_.split(" ")).map(r => 
    (r(0).dropRight(3), r(2).toInt)) val result = 
    converted.reduceByKey(_ + _)
    sc.stop() } }
```

The result is

```
(M2001,7) (D2001,24) (M2003,3) (D2003,3) (D2002,22) (D2004,10) (B2002,1) (B2004,10)
```

I would want the result to be

```
(Magazine, 2001 ,7)
(Dictionary, 2001, 24)
(Magazine ,2003, 3)
(Dictionary, 2003, 3).
```

And so on.

A simple function would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this help?

```
rdd.map(_.split(" "))
   .map(str => ((str.head.head match {
        case 'M' => "Magazine"
        case 'B' => "Book"
        case 'D' => "Dictionary"
        case _ => ???
      }, str.head.drop(1).dropRight(3).toInt), str.last.toInt))
   .reduceByKey(_ + _)
   .map(tuple => (tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2))
```

Example output (verified):

(Magazine,2003,3), (Dictionary,2001,24), (Dictionary,2003,3), 
(Book,2002,1), (Magazine,2001,7), (Book,2004,10), 
(Dictionary,2002,22), (Dictionary,2004,10)

Comment: I've deleted my code and replaced it with yours. It gave me an error where there was 'row._1' it said "value _1 is not a member of String"

Comment: I used a case class in my example. I will add the fix

Comment: Thank you very much! I added the println so i can print out the results